# unresolved classes and Attribute errors in the manifest

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, manifest

I am new to android developing, I had some errors which I couldn't find a solution for.
The problem is with the Manifest.xml file and the styles file.
This is the Manifest file and I get the following errors:
Attribute android:allowBackup is not allowed here
Attribute android:icon is not allowed here
Attribute android:roundIcon is not allowed here
Attribute android:supportsRtl is not allowed here
Attribute android:theme is not allowed here
Unresolved package 'activities'
Unresolved class 'MyDiagnosisActivity'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".activities.MyDiagnosisActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

This is the strings file

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MyDiagnosis</string>
<string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
</resources>
```

This is the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mydiagnosis"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions({
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        })
    }

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0-alpha02'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.0.0-alpha02")
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.1'

    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3"

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}
```

Also there is an error in the Styles file:
Cannot resolve symbol 'colorPrimary'
Cannot resolve symbol 'colorPrimaryDark'
Cannot resolve symbol 'colorAccent'

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
</style>
```

Note: I have already tried: Rebuild the project, Invalidate and restart, change the android version to beta, change anything in the Gradle file and then sync and then undo and resync.
Sorry if my problem may seem so dumb, I am a high school student and I have tried my best to solve these errors.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Find the build.gradle file in the root directory of your project and rewrite the file as

```
 repositories {
        maven{ url'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

---

You need to add the following to your manifest.

```
<application
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:allowBackup">
```

```
<manifest package="xxx"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Hope this could help with your issue. :)

Comment: I did exactly as you said but it only added a new error, "Attribute tools:replace is not allowed here".

Comment: hi@Hazem Shereef ,i updated my answer,pls kindly refer

Comment: Hi @shirley, I did like you said but also the errors remain.  I have put the code in the build.gradle and resync and the build finishes successfully, however the same error are there. by the way here is the whole code "github.com/VishwaP98/MyDiagnosis"